# Select array value by key name

Tags: php, arrays

Before I receive a hail of snark please believe me - I have googled and used SO search.

How do I select an array value by name?

If I wanted to call particular values (for a db connection) how would I do that here? The following is the database.php file in config folder for PHP based CMS site.

I'd like to create the connection for a mysqli query

```
$db_connection = @mysqli_connect(host,user,pass,database)
```

The code below exists in a separate file in the site's config folder config/database.php.

```
$config['default'] = array(
        'benchmark' => TRUE,
        'persistent' => FALSE,
        'connection' => array(
            'type' => 'mysqli',
            'user' => 'myname',
            'pass' => 'somepass123',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => FALSE,
            'socket' => FALSE,
            'database' => 'local_sitename',
        ),
        'character_set' => 'utf8',
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'object' => TRUE,
        'cache' => FALSE,
        'escape' => TRUE
    );
```

The internet, and my text book, are full of examples like this: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php6p3.html

Where, for example, is a seasons array:

```
<?php

$seasons = array("Autumn", "Winter", "Spring", "Summer");
print $seasons[0];

?>
```

I know that I could select say Spring by using `$seasons[2];`

But using the array in my sites config file uses arrays within an array. I need something like (This will be syntactically wrong but I hope conveys what I need)

```
$db_connection = $config(connection(host)),$config(connection(user)),$config(connection(pass)),$config(connection(database))
```

How would I call these values?

Comment: `$config['default']['connection']['host']` - basic array access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$config['default'] = array(
        'benchmark' => TRUE,
        'persistent' => FALSE,
        'connection' => array(
            'type' => 'mysqli',
            'user' => 'myname',
            'pass' => 'somepass123',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => FALSE,
            'socket' => FALSE,
            'database' => 'local_sitename',
        ),
        'character_set' => 'utf8',
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'object' => TRUE,
        'cache' => FALSE,
        'escape' => TRUE
    );


echo $config['default']['connection']['user'] // prints myname
echo $config['default']['connection']['pass'] // prints pass
echo $config['default']['connection']['host'] // prints host
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. So, this seems pretty long, in PHP is there no shorter way? I tried $config['connection'] because connection appears to be an array with all the required info

Comment: Well there are multiple ways of setting up connection. You can store it in constants -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php
Or just in base variables or you can make config array just for database

Answer (score 1):

Use strings to index your array by key:

```
$config['default']['connection']['host'];// === 'localhost'
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer I realize this is basic to those who follow the php tag

Comment: @Doug Not those who *"follow the PHP tag"*. Those who *read the manual and learned PHP by reading tutorials or books.* I'd recommend you do more of either.